# Java How to find a specific line after a specific string?

Tags: java

I got a text from a BufferedReader and I need to get a specific line after a specific string

This is the text for example:

```
<img src="https://example.com/image1.jpg">
<img src="https://example.com/image2.jpg">
<img src="https://example.com/image3.jpg">
<img src="https://example.com/image4.jpg">
<all>
<img src="https://example.com/image9.jpg">
<img src="https://example.com/image11.jpg">
<img src="https://example.com/image15.jpg">
```

example with linebreak

```
<img src="https://example.com/image1.jpg">
<img src="https://example.com/image2.jpg">
<img src="https://example.com/image3.jpg">
<img src="https://example.com/image4.jpg">
<all>

<img src="https://example.com/image9.jpg">
<img src="https://example.com/image11.jpg">
<img src="https://example.com/image15.jpg">
```

example with other character

```
<img src="https://example.com/image1.jpg">
<img src="https://example.com/image2.jpg">
<img src="https://example.com/image3.jpg">
<img src="https://example.com/image4.jpg">
<all>
UTUYGBLK
<img src="https://example.com/image9.jpg">
<img src="https://example.com/image11.jpg">
<img src="https://example.com/image15.jpg">
```

I only want the img src line after 'all' which cont and end loop after that. the image number are random so I cant possible hit any of those.

currently my code is as follows.

```
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

  if (line.contains("all"))  {    
    line = rd.readLine();   
    System.out.println(line);
  }
 }
```

but if there is a linebreak after the 'all' i will get a null return... or funny character UTUYGBLK

Comment: Set a flag if you encounter `"all"` and continue looping.  Then return the first line for which `!line.trim().isEmpty()`. (BTW, your current code should not return `null` but an empty string if the next line is blank.  `null` would only be returned if the last line in the file is matched in which case there is no “line after it”.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to loop after the  element then until the result is not null. The code below should protect you against reading lines after end of file and also stop after the first line is shown after  is read.

```
boolean loop = true;
// global loop
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null && loop) {
  // line with "all" in it is found?
  if(line.contains("all"))  {    
    // Continue going through the input until end of input
    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null && loop) {  
      // When the line is not empty you have found the line after all!
      if(!line.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(line);
        // to stop the loops
        loop = false; 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The expression line != null will always be true, because (line = ...) != null is part of the loop condition.

Answer (score 1):

Then just skip the blank lines.

```
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

    if (line.contains("all"))  {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null && line.trim().isEmpty());
        System.out.println(line);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't cover end of input case.

Comment: @Juru Now it does. I thought there must come at least one valid line by definition - but we can never know ;)

Comment: I never try to assume too much :). That way of thinking came back at me for revenge many times.

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = "";
while (!line.contains("all"))
    line = rd.readLine();
line = rd.readLine();
while ("".equals(line.trim()))
    line = rd.readLine();
return line;
//or System.out.println(line);
```

This will:

1. Set `line` to the empty string.
2. Read lines until it gets one containing `all`.
3. Read the next line.
4. Read lines until it gets a non-empty one.
5. Return the last thing it read.

This operates on the assumption that there really will be a line containing `all`, and that there really will be a non-blank somewhere after it.

Answer (score 0):

You can go into a second loop to check for nulls.

```
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

        if (line.contains("all"))  {    
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) == null || line.isEmpty()) {
                  //keep looping while line is null

                  //check if it is no longer ready to avoid infinite loop
                  if (!rd.ready()) {break;}
            }
            //line should not be null here
            System.out.println(line);
       }
```

Or something to that affect.

Comment: Infinite loop when you are at the end of the input.

Comment: @Juru thanks for the heads up.  How about now?  I added a ready() check.

Comment: Better, but you might also have an empty string instead of null, null indicates end of input and the empty string would mean an empty line.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that also but the OP was concerned with NULL not empty... but I'll add the empty check to make it more complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you use contains() if you have an image with a name containing 'all' you will have incorrect results. Better use equals() after trimming the line. So the code will look like this:

```
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null ) {
    if (line.trim().equals("<all>"))  {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()).isEmpty());
        System.out.println(line);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the method

```
line.isEmpty()
```

to handle that case